# Чем можно заменить оператор if?

Tags: c#

Есть большой массив чисел, допустим от -1млн до 1млн. При существовании какой-либо числа в этом масиве необходимо выполнить условие. Как, не проверяя каждый элемент if'ом, выполнить условие?

UPD: Вообще, меня интересует вопрос быстродействия, ведь каждый раз проверять отдельный элемент на соответсвие условию, по моему мнеию, не совсем рационально. Может есть какие-то другие споспобы выполнения данной задачи?

Comment: Зависит от условия. Оно каждый раз разное? Приведите пример вашего кода.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14882319/12888024

Comment: Кстати, если массив отсортирован, то можно бинарный поиск приплести

Comment: И всё же уточните задачу. Она просто в том, чтобы не использовать именно `if` или суть не в этом? И ещё - как часто планируется искать такие элементы?

Comment: `Вообще, меня интересует вопрос быстродействия` быстродействия чего? Вы же свою задачу не расписали.

Answer (score 2):

Сделать заранее из этого массива `HashSet`, тогда проверка будет моментальная - просто проверяете, что число есть в этом `HashSet`, это делается за время `O(1)`.

Comment: Но стоит иметь в виду, что если проверка требуется всего одна, то создание HashSet окажется лишь пустой тратой времени. А автор не уточнил, сколько проверок ему надо

Comment: @andreymal Да автор вообще мало деталей раскрыл, это да )

Comment: _Да автор вообще мало деталей раскрыл_, автор вопроса новичёк, он ещё не совсем понимает - как задать хороший вопрос. Ему никто и не помог, пока нет ни одного уточняюшего комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Если вас беспокоит красота записи, то можно проверить наличие элемента в массиве следующим образом:

```
var arrayInt = new int[] { -1000000, 0, 1000000 };
if (Array.Exists(arrayInt, i => i == 3))
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```